# Folder disappear from desktop unable to paste copied files on desktop

Tags: 22.04

This happens after the last update on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I noticed I was unable to share screen on any platform (zoom, Google Meet, Anydesk).
Also, Folders and Files disappear from the desktop.

[image: screenshot]

I only get these 3 options by right-clicking on my desktop.
Somehow I fixed screen sharing by switching to X11 from Wayland but still, I am unable to paste any files or folders on the desktop

Answer (score 0):

Desktop icons in Ubuntu desktop are provided by a build-in Gnome Shell extension, "Desktop Icons NG (DING)". According to what you describe, that extension is not anymore enabled.

Load the "Extensions" tool (if not installed, then install it first) and check the status of the Gnome Shell extensions. Check whether extensions are turned on (switch on the first line). If off, then toggle that on and check whether the individual extensions are enabled.

[image]

If you cannot have the build in extension to work, then first disable any custom extensions you may have installed, then log out and back in before trying to enable the "Desktop Icons NG (DING)" extension.